# take from back the first 3 characters from a string

Tags: php, html, substring

Let's say I have the following string:

```
$dynamicstring = "19949510234";
```

I want to get everything **but** the last 8 characters from the string.
In this case that would be the first 3 characters, but there can be 2 or 1 as well.
This is what I tried, but if I put 2 characters instead of 3 it still returns 3 characters and I don't want that.

```
$dynamicstring = "19949510234";
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring,-8,-3);
echo "The new string is: " . $newstring;
```

Comment: Didn't understand anything, give some examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract `8` from the length of the string and use that as an argument to `substr`:

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, 0, strlen($dynamicstring) - 8);
```